# Why are Divs Getting Width of 0px on jQuery.show() with jQueryEasyUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-easyui

I have a parent div that is initially hidden. Inside the div I have an easyui accordion div. When I called the show() method on the parent div, the easyui div displays with a width of 0px. If the div isn't initally hidden, it calculates a width fine.

Does anyone know the proper way to initially hide a div and then when showing it calculate the proper width?

```
<div id='masterDiv' style='display:none;'>
    <div class="easyui-accordion" style='height:475px;' data-options="border:false" > 
        <div title="Overview" class='accordionPanel' data-options="iconCls:'icon-no'" style="overflow:auto;padding:10px;">  
            <h3 style="color:#0099FF;">Accordion for jQuery</h3>  
            <p>Accordion is a part of easyui framework for jQuery. It lets you define your accordion component on web page more easily.</p>  
        </div>
        <div title="Checklist" class='accordionPanel' data-options="iconCls:'icon-no'" style="overflow:auto;padding:10px;">  
            <h3 style="color:#0099FF;">Accordion for jQuery</h3>  
            <p>Accordion is a part of easyui framework for jQuery. It lets you define your accordion component on web page more easily.</p>  
        </div>
     </div>
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#masterDiv').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

hey i ran into the exact same problem for the exact same reason as the comment you made. I ended up doing the display:none then manually added each css change that was made. First i made the masterDiv into a class

```
$('.masterDiv').css("display", "block");
$('.masterDiv' .accordian).css('width', '300px);
```

accordian being whatever the class easyUI set to a width of 0px. It ended up being a lot of css code but it works until Jquery EasyUI can come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are hiding the div, if it has to be shown after pageload ?

Did you try

```
document.getElementById("masterDiv").style.display="block";
```

Comment: I'm hiding the accordion and other components until the document is fully loaded to avoid "flashing" on the screen in IE on load. The above statement does not work. Unfortunately, I have a feeling this is a bug in jQuery EasyUI. I joined their forum months ago, but they never approved my username so I can't ask any questions there :(